# Page becomes unreponsive when size of select2 dropdown options increases more than 25000

Tags: performance, load, dropdown, jquery-select2

Page becomes un-reponsive when size of select2 dropdown options increases more than 25000. Plugin is applied and page loads rightly when dropdown options count is just below twenty thousands.

Any other plugin if it supports large sized drop-downs having more than fifty thousand options...?

Comment: How is an end user going to navigate through 25,000 options?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful article to cater the slowness issue with too large dropdown options of select2 here:

https://www.knowband.com/blog/ecommerce-blog/handle-large-data-select2-dropdown/